# How do I delete models from a backbone.js localStorage collection properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using backbone-localstorage plugin for caching data from server. I am using jquery ajax to manually fetch data from the server and then add to the backbone collection.
Each time the page is loaded I remove the existing data from the local storage and then load fresh data from server.

I am using the following code :

```
success : function(response){
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
            var channelList = new NewsApp.channelCollection();
            channelList.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("channellist");
            channelList.fetch();

            //Clear the current items from the localStorage so as not to exceed the localstorage limit
            channelList.each(function(model) {
                console.log("Channel Removed");
                model.destroy();
            } );

            _.each(json.channel, function(channel){
                channelList.create(channel);
            });

            console.log(channelList);
}
```

This works fine the first time I run it. But when I run it the second time, **some** of the models from the last execution still persist in the collection.

Is this the proper method for inserting and removing data from the backbone localstorage ?

Comment: This is a strange way to use Backbone. You should really let Backone handle the ajax call, or override the fetch method of your collection. Anyway, try removing the channelList.fetch line. Since you're not using the collection's ajax call you should remove that call to fetch.

Comment: Thanks @GregRoss I switched to backbone.dualStorage plugin